# using .index(" ") for nested list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I want to get the index of the "4" in the nested list, it is working cause I suppress the error. any idea for a alternative?

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        index = a[i].index(4)
        print(i, index)  
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: There are lots of alternatives, but no clear reason for suggesting any particular one over what you currently have.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code that won't throw an error and doesn't use index() function.

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j] == 4:
            print("Found at", i, j)
            break
```

Comment: Well done because `a[1][0]` returns the 4 that was searched in the first place.

Comment: why are you using `range`? it's much better to use the iterable itself, if you need the index too, use `enumerate`

Answer (score 3):

The `index` method will raise in a `ValueError` if the element is not found in the list. This is why the first iteration throws an exception.
You can either catch the error or check if the element is in the list before using the `index` method.

Here's an example:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def find_index(list_of_lists, item):
    for sublist in list_of_lists:
        try:
            return sublist.index(item)
        except ValueError:
            continue

print(find_index(a, 4))
```

Which yields 0 as expected.

Alternatively, you could implement a `look-before-you-leap` approach and check if the element exists in the list before attempting to use the `index` method. This is less efficient however, because checking if an element exists in a list is a linear time operation.

```
def find_index(list_of_lists, item):
    for sublist in list_of_lists:
        if item in sublist:
            return sublist.index(item)
```

This is less efficient and less "pythonic", but still viable.

Comment: It's not necessarily much less efficient to look before you leap. `list.index` is a linear time operation too, the only difference is that it raises an exception if it reaches the end of the list before finding a match.

Comment: The asymptotic time complexity is the same, but using the `in` operator kind of doubles it needlessly.